# Accepting IPv4 and IPv6 connections on a single port using Boost.Asio

Tags: c++, network-programming, boost-asio, ipv6

I intend to use `tcp::acceptor` to accept both IPv4 and IPv6 connections on a single local port, say `55555`. My code ends up in something like this:

```
tcp::acceptor acceptor_ipv4(io_svc, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 55555));
tcp::acceptor acceptor_ipv6(io_svc, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v6(), 55555));
acceptor_ipv4.async_accept(socket_ipv4, ...);
acceptor_ipv6.async_accept(socket_ipv6, ...);
```

I'm new to network programming and Boost.Asio, and want to make sure whether this is correct code or not, or if there is any portability issue.

Comment: Does it work or not?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Seems to work on my Win 7 64bit.

Comment: Well, test it on a Linux machine and if it works, you'll pretty well have your answer.

Comment: One caveat to pay attention to is that on some OS there is a flag to decide whether a socket listening on IPv6 will only receive IPv6 connections or both IPv4 and IPv6 connections. If the socket is set to receive both IPv4 and IPv6, the second bind call will fail because the port number is already in use on IPv4. And it appears you have no error checking in your code, which means if that error occurred it may not be obvious what just happened.

Comment: @kasperd The acceptor's constructor will throw on error with a message corresponding to the failed bind.

Comment: @TannerSansbury That could address the issue with the reason for such an error condition not being obvious.

Comment: @kasperd Will it happen even when the third parameter `reuse_addr` is set to `true`? See the third constructor overload here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket_acceptor/basic_socket_acceptor.html

Answer (score 1):

@kasperd's comment is correct, your implementation may not be portable.
I recommend that you read this from the great man himself: [Are you ready for IPV6?](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boostcon/2011_presentations/master/wed/IPv6.pdf)